# Python CSV multithreading queue() issue

Tags: python, multithreading, csv

I am at the beginning of writing a multithreaded script that reads input from csv files with a single column of data I wish to read into a `queue()`.  That would happen in `f(q):`.  Then I will read from the queue in the worker function and do some stuff then output a new csv with data.  Where I am stuck is that no matter where I put `q.put([urls])` indented I only manage to capture a single value in the queue().  Why is it not looping through the urls like the `print urls` statement does? Any help is appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
import csv
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Pool

#read rows in input file into the queue()
def f(q):
    with open('test.csv', 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            urls = row[0]
            print urls
            q.put([urls])


#process the queue() and write output
def worker():
    # do work
    # ...
    # here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue()
    p = Process(target=f, args=(q,))
    p.start()
    print q.get()    # prints urls as queue output debug
    p.join()
```

Comment: the `q.put([urls])` is outside the loop so it will only add the last `urls`

Comment: @GIRISHRAMNANI I changed the indent and reran the program.  Now what I get is the proper print of the urls loop, but it hangs when it gets to the queue() portion of the code.  Thoughts?

Comment: Doesn't hang for me.

Comment: @user1763208 can you try it multiple times. if in any of the times if you code executes that means that your code is in a dead lock sometimes .can you remove the `print q.get()`  which is after `p.start()`

Comment: @GIRISHRAMNANI without the print portion after p.start() the program just hangs and doesn;t run.  Something has to be wrong with this syntax.