# how to use multi-threading for optimizing face detection?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have a code which uses a list of image URLs from a CSV file and then performs face detection on those images after which it loads some models and does predictions on those images.

I did some load tests and found that the **get_face** function in the code takes a major chunk of the time required to produce the results and the extra time is taken by the pickle file created for predictions.

**Question**: Is there a possibility that by running these processes in threads, time can be reduced and also how this can be done in a multi threading way?

Here is the code example:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np

from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Pool
import os
import pickle
import pandas as pd
import dlib
from skimage import io
from skimage.transform import resize

df = pd.read_csv('/home/instaurls.csv')
detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
img_width, img_height = 139, 139
confidence = 0.8

def get_face():
    output = None
    data1 = []
    for row in df.itertuples():
        img = io.imread(row[1])
        dets = detector(img, 1)
        for i, d in enumerate(dets):
            img = img[d.top():d.bottom(), d.left():d.right()]
            img = resize(img, (img_width, img_height))
            output = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
            break
        data1.append(output)
    data1 = np.concatenate(data1)
    return data1

get_face()
```

**csv sample**

```
data
https://scontent-frt3-2.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s320x320/23101834_1502115223199537_1230866541029883904_n.jpg
https://scontent-frt3-2.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s320x320/17883193_940000882769400_8455736118338387968_a.jpg
https://scontent-frt3-2.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s320x320/22427207_1737576603205281_7879421442167668736_n.jpg
https://scontent-frt3-2.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s320x320/12976287_1720757518213286_1180118177_a.jpg
https://scontent-frt3-2.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s320x320/23101834_1502115223199537_1230866541029883904_n.jpg
https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s320x320/16788491_748497378632253_566270225134125056_a.jpg
https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s320x320/21819738_128551217878233_9151523109507956736_n.jpg
https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s320x320/14295447_318848895135407_524281974_a.jpg
https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s320x320/18160229_445050155844926_2783054824017494016_a.jpg
https://scontent-frt3-2.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s320x320/23101834_1502115223199537_1230866541029883904_n.jpg
https://scontent-frt3-2.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s320x320/17883193_940000882769400_8455736118338387968_a.jpg
https://scontent-frt3-2.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s320x320/22427207_1737576603205281_7879421442167668736_n.jpg
https://scontent-frt3-2.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s320x320/12976287_1720757518213286_1180118177_a.jpg
https://scontent-frt3-2.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s320x320/23101834_1502115223199537_1230866541029883904_n.jpg
https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s320x320/16788491_748497378632253_566270225134125056_a.jpg
https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s320x320/21819738_128551217878233_9151523109507956736_n.jpg
https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s320x320/14295447_318848895135407_524281974_a.jpg
https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s320x320/18160229_445050155844926_2783054824017494016_a.jpg
https://scontent-frt3-2.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s320x320/23101834_1502115223199537_1230866541029883904_n.jpg
```

Comment: You shouldn't use pandas to read a csv of urls... even less to store the image back. Pandas is not a database. As you have it now, it's (in my opinion) impossible to do any multithreading as the `get_face` function loads everything into a dataframe.

Comment: By the look of it, `get_face` is CPU bound and using Python threads is not of much use in that case. You should concentrate on `multiprocessing` module and create pool of processes. This way you will be able to utilize more than one CPU core.

Comment: @IgnacioVergaraKausel what's your suggestion? i used pandas to avoid a for loop for going through rows of the csv and in the function i am loading everything into a numpy array; not a dataframe

Comment: @ikac how should i do multiprocessing on this function? i am new in paralllel computing

Comment: @Rehan but you still do `df.iterrows` which from what I've seen everywhere is not very recommended. To make it friendly for any kind of parallel computing, perhaps you should start by using a queue where you put the images as you get them while other threads/process pull from it. I don't think you will be able to get away of serially parse your file with URLs, but I guess that's not much of the bottleneck

Comment: @IgnacioVergaraKausel i am thinking of doing something like this but still this will create a loop and thus slow down the process    
`with open('test.csv', 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            urls = row[0]
            print urls
            q.put([urls])`

Comment: @Rehan it might slow down a bit, provided pandas is better at reading a csv... but I don't think that's your bottleneck. You did say that the function `get_face` is the one that uses most of the time and that one is the one you should try to parallelize. Actually, that function should be called `get_faces` as it process all of them. You should make a real `get_face` that takes as an argument just one image. that's your first step to parallel and use a queue to control the flow from the url reader to the taks.

Comment: Like @IgnacioVergaraKausel said, you have to make `get_face` do a recognition process on one image, i.e. to make smallest unit/chunk of work. Then you make a pool of processes and pass them each chunk of work. You can even experiment with how much images you want to pass to worker processes. That would in essence mean you increase a size of work chunk. That can give you benefit if processing single image is quick, but you have lot of worker processes and a lot of images to process.

Comment: @Rehan I can't give you specific instructions since you have a lot of function calls and I don't know how those work. I can't even run this code since it's not a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @ikac i modified the code according to MCVE maybe now you can provide some input. i have certain confusions : 
1. if not padas dataframe then how should i read csv in a optimized way?
2. how should i make a pool of processes ? something like this https://stackoverflow.com/q/35568116/4866548

Comment: @Rehan not really.. what is the function `detector`? This code cannot be run as it is (missing import statements!). Again, reading the csv is the least of your problems... and probably the best way would be reading line by line (since it's not really a csv but a collection of links) using a generator.

Comment: now the code is fixed and why would you downvote my question. everybody is here for learning. don't discourage beginners!

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you could try to do it in parallel:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np

from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Pool
import os
import pickle
import pandas as pd
import dlib
from skimage import io
from skimage.transform import resize
from csv import DictReader

df = DictReader(open('/home/instaurls.csv')) # DictReader is iterable
detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector() 
img_width, img_height = 139, 139
confidence = 0.8

def get_face(row):
    """
    Here row is dictionary where keys are CSV header names
    and values are values from current CSV row.
    """
    output = None

    img = io.imread(row[1]) # row[1] has to be changed to row['data']?
    dets = detector(img, 1)
    for i, d in enumerate(dets):
        img = img[d.top():d.bottom(), d.left():d.right()]
        img = resize(img, (img_width, img_height))
        output = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
        break

    return output

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool() # default to number CPU cores
    data = list(pool.imap(get_face, df))
    print np.concatenate(data)
```

Pay attention to `get_face` and argument that it has. Also, to what it returns. This is what I meant when I said smaller chunks of work. Now `get_face` processes one row from CSV.

When you run this script, `pool` will be a reference to a instance of a `Pool` and you then call `get_face` for each row/tuple in `df.itertuples()`.

After everything is done, `data` holds processing data and then you do `np.concatenate` on it.

Comment: I guess, since each call to `get_face` are independent, using threads instead of multiprocessing would be a better idea. Probably using `concurrent.futures`, which allows an easy swapping between processes adn threads would make sense here too.

Comment: I recognized this function as CPU intensive i.e. CPU bound. In that case, because of GIL you will only have one thread running at any time. Because of GIL and swapping between multiple threads that introduces additional overhead, you will get worse performance than doing it without any parallellization at all. It would be different case if `get_face` was I/O bound. Then you'd have better performance with threads since each of them will be mostly waiting for I/O.

Comment: @ikac thanks a lot for providing solution. i integrated the code but i still have some issues. the concatenate statement returns an error that **zero dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated**. i tried printing just the data object without any concatenation just below the imap function and it returns only one object of imap iterator although it should be returning multiple due to recursive calls

Comment: Oops, a mistake sneaked in. Make sure to update code, I have revised the solution. Hint: `data = list(pool....)` and not `data = [pool...]`. Reason is because `imap` returns `iterator` and it has to be 'unrolled'.

Comment: @ikac now it gives me strange pickling error for the same line. this error

`_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'pandas.core.frame.Pandas'>: attribute lookup Pandas on pandas.core.frame failed `

Comment: Can you add sample of csv file in your question, so we can come up with different way of reading it?

Comment: @ikac i just added a sample. the original has 1000 rows with data as the title at the top.

Comment: Please check the solution again. And in `get_face` there was accessing `row[1]` value. Now, `row` is a dictionary, and probably `row['data']` should be accessed.